# Linux kernel module makefile issues

Tags: linux, compilation, makefile, kernel

I am trying to learn a little about Linux kernel programming, and after trying a tutorial i am completely stuck.
My makefile is complaining about some sort of "Command not found" error (error 127), so it won't compile it.
I tried searching for a solution, but nothing came up. So I thought I'd try to ask here. Sorry if this is a duplicate.

Here is the error output from the shell:

```
malt@ubuntu:~/Documents/C$ make
C /usr/src/linux SUBDIRS=/home/malt/Documents/C; modules
/bin/sh: 1: C: not found
/bin/sh: 1: modules: not found
make: [default] Error 127 (ignored)
```

And here is my makefile:

```
# Makefile of My First Driver

# if KERNELRELEASE is defined, we've been invoked from the kernel build system
# and can use it's language
ifneq (${KERNELRELEASE},)
    obj-m := mfd.o

# otherwise we've been called directly from the commandline.
# invoke the kernel build system.
else
    KERNEL_SOURCE := /usr/src/linux
    PWD := ${shell pwd};

default:
    ${make} -C ${KERNEL_SOURCE} SUBDIRS=${PWD} modules

clean:
    ${make} -C ${KERNEL_SOURCE} SUBDIRS=${PWD} clean

endif
```

Does anyone have any idea as to what is wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to Santosh A's Changes

1. There shouldn't be `;` in  `PWD := ${shell pwd};`. remove it which will solve `/bin/sh: 1: modules: not found` error.

Answer (score 1):

change keyword make to MAKE as below

> default:
>            ${**MAKE**} -C ${KERNEL_SOURCE} SUBDIRS=${PWD} modules 
>       clean:
>   ${**MAKE**} -C ${KERNEL_SOURCE} SUBDIRS=${PWD} clean

Comment: Why should "MAKE" be in capital letters? I understand the rest, but I am curious about that.
Thanks though.

Comment: make is a keyword that shouldn't be used